# java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found

Tags: java, fonts

I am using same code of jfreechart in linux and windows with zkoss.

When i run same code in windows it runs fine, but in linux it gives font related error as under....

Can anyone please suggest me how can i resolve this issue permanently ?

**java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found.**

```
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1087)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1070)
sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:959)
sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:898)
sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:915)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1903)
sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1864)
java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:477)
sun.font.FontManager.getFont2D(Native Method)
sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:356)
sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:349)
sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:301)
sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:787)
org.jfree.text.TextFragment.calculateDimensions(TextFragment.java:229)
org.jfree.text.TextLine.calculateDimensions(TextLine.java:190)
org.jfree.text.TextBlock.calculateDimensions(TextBlock.java:171)
org.jfree.chart.block.LabelBlock.arrange(LabelBlock.java:316)
org.jfree.chart.block.BorderArrangement.arrangeNN(BorderArrangement.java:210)
org.jfree.chart.block.BorderArrangement.arrange(BorderArrangement.java:137)
org.jfree.chart.block.BlockContainer.arrange(BlockContainer.java:179)
org.jfree.chart.block.CenterArrangement.arrangeNN(CenterArrangement.java:284)
org.jfree.chart.block.CenterArrangement.arrange(CenterArrangement.java:98)
org.jfree.chart.block.BlockContainer.arrange(BlockContainer.java:179)
org.jfree.chart.block.FlowArrangement.arrangeNN(FlowArrangement.java:365)
org.jfree.chart.block.FlowArrangement.arrangeRR(FlowArrangement.java:283)
org.jfree.chart.block.FlowArrangement.arrange(FlowArrangement.java:158)
org.jfree.chart.block.BlockContainer.arrange(BlockContainer.java:179)
org.jfree.chart.title.LegendTitle.arrange(LegendTitle.java:501)
org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.drawTitle(JFreeChart.java:1330)
org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(JFreeChart.java:1220)
```

Comment: Linux APAUTODNS1-1 2.6.32-202.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 21 15:27:03 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2.6.32-202.el6.x86_64
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.3) (rhel-1.40.1.10.3.el6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Server built:   Nov 28 2011 11:20:06
Server number:  6.0.35.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-202.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.6.0_22-b22
JVM Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.

Answer (score 19):

under Ubuntu you can install fonts by

```
    sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu
```

or if you use CentOS, you can install fonts by

```
    yum install dejavu*
```

Comment: Works. I also had to restart tomcat6.

Comment: If tested using java -jar command then the process needs to be stopped and re-run again to get it reflected.

Answer (score 5):

In my case (debian wheezy) installing the dejavu font does not solve the problem.

I have solved after installing the fontconfig package

sudo apt-get install fontconfig

Comment: In CentOS 7, same result. Not only need to install dejavu* fonts, but also need to install fontconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9 Stretch
Install Fonts: sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu
Install fontconfig: sudo apt-get install fontconfig
Rebuild the font cache: fc-cache -f -v
Restart Tomcat

Works

Answer (score 0):

Try putting same `Windows` fonts that are required for the application in `Linux` fonts directory.

Comment: Hello Imran, Thanks for your reply. I have already tried it but it didn't work. Can you please tell me any other way in detail to solve it ?

Comment: check your JDK. It might be an issue.

Comment: I also have uninstalld and again installed JDK. But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class, which ran on the server, to figure out which fonts the JVM could accept. And I used one of them, but it didn't work either. What really solved my problem was this command: sudo apt-get install fontconfig. I'm using Ubuntu and consequently I had to restart the system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).